# Where to define include or link path variables in Visual Studio 2010 (and higher)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to build a C++ project with Visual Studio 2010 and 
Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> 
Additional Include Directories uses path variables, for example APR_DIST as shown below:

```
..\src\test-integration;..\src\main;$(APR_DIST)\$(PlatformName)\include;$(CPPUNIT_DIST)\$(PlatformName)\include;$(PLATFORM_SDK)\include
```

So how do I define those variables/macros ?

I would expect to find a config file that says APR_DIST=... or someplace in 
Visual Studio. 
Also, I know about editing the path and click on Macros>> but I can not add or edit anything there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're environment variables and they're system or user-wide. It depends on your version of Windows how you can read and alter them but [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/284351/268404) describes it pretty well.

Comment: These are system wide ? Wow, ok. But it works - thanks. Also what helped me was to watch closely what happens to C/C++ -> Command Line

Comment: The error of Visual Studio should probably say something like "Can not find environment variable APR_DIST, please specify?" Or at least say "can't find variable APR_DIST" instead of continuing with the compile.